# Can I get the argmax in jq?

Tags: json, jq

The following dataset contains movies. I want to find the longest title with `jq`. What I got so far:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prust/wikipedia-movie-data/master/movies.json
$ cat movies.json | jq '[.[] | .title | length] | max'
```

So the longest title has 110 characters. The following query the shows it to me:

```
$ cat movies.json | jq '.[] | .title | select(length==110)' 
"Cornell-Columbia-University of Pennsylvania Boat Race at Ithaca, N.Y., Showing Lehigh Valley Observation Train"
```

Is it possible to directly get the argmax?

### Background

I am currently trying what I can do with `jq` for exploratory data analysis. Usually, I would use Pandas for most of it. However, I recently had an example where jq was just super handy. So I want to learn more about it to see how far jq can go / where it is easier to use than Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `max_by` like:

```
max_by(.title | length).title
```

or,

```
map(.title) | max_by(length)
```